# Does $.ajaxSetup works only for calls inside the same file?

Tags: jquery

update.apsx page contains an ajax call to update some data, this aspx page include a javascript file common.js, inside common.js i added this code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('AntiForgery-Token', $('#hidUserToken').val());
  }
});
```

but the code inside is never called.

the update.aspx page also include jquery-1.8.3.min.js before common.js.
do i have to move $.ajaxSetup inside the same file where the ajax calls are (update.aspx) ?

ajax call inside update.aspx

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "./ws/xxx.svc/UpdateUser",
  data: dataToSend,
  processData: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success:
  function(ResultUpdate) {
  ...
  }
  ,
  error:
  function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  ...
  }
  });
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does $.ajaxSetup works only for calls inside the same file?

Depends what you mean by 'file'. The `$.ajaxSetup()` call will be applied to the jQuery instance within the current page.

You could have multiple JS files each dealing with their own logic. If one of them calls `$.ajaxSetup()`, then any AJAX call made by jQuery after that will apply the global AJAX settings.

> The update.aspx page also include jquery-1.8.3.min.js before common.js. Do I have to move `$.ajaxSetup` inside the same file where the AJAX calls are (update.aspx)?

No. So long as `$.ajaxSetup()` is called *before* you make any AJAX call, from any other JS file referenced in the page, then its settings will be applied, unless specifically overridden.

Comment: perhaps the problem lies in the fact that the ajax calls are inside the aspx Page, not in js file?

Comment: Not at all, the location of the JS script makes no difference so long as the sequence maintains dependencies.